# How to install the AMD ADL library on ubuntu

Tags: linux, video, driver, argument-dependent-lookup, ati

The latest ATI blockchain drivers doesn't include the ADL.
The installation instructions in the ADL release refer to the included adlutil, but how can I install the library so 3rd party software (like Claymore) can use it?

Any help'd be appreciated.

https://developer.amd.com/display-library-adl-sdk/